# pd.DataFrame() fails when combining 2 lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 lists like below while my lists actually have 3000 elements:

```
a=[numpy.datetime64('2004-04-12T08:00:00.000000000+0800'),numpy.datetime64('2004-04-12T08:00:00.000000000+0800'),numpy.datetime64('2004-04-12T08:00:00.000000000+0800')]
b=[1,2,3]
```

When I tried to combine them to form a dataframe with 2 columns:
    `c=pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(a), pd.Series(b)])`
It says: `TypeError: invalid type promotion`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
c = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':a,'b':b})
```

You're getting the error because you are trying to create a pandas dataframe by putting two lists together into one column, while the data types of the elements in those lists don't match. Basically, you're trying to put dates and integers into the same column.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, since your answer is the earliest, I'd tick it.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'a': [
        np.datetime64('2004-04-12T08:00:00.000000000+0800'),
        np.datetime64('2004-04-12T08:00:00.000000000+0800'),
        np.datetime64('2004-04-12T08:00:00.000000000+0800')
    ],
    'b': [1, 2, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work without using a dictionary:

```
c = pd.DataFrame([a, b]).T
print c
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b))

           0  1
0 2004-04-12  1
1 2004-04-12  2
2 2004-04-12  3
```